# laptop WIn 8.1 partition not displayed on grub

Tags: grubrescue

Iḿ new to Ubuntu. When I start the laptop the only Os displayed in Grub is Ubuntu.

So can I get my Windows 8.1 Os back up and running? and how?

Thank you all in advanced.

Gparted:
 [image]

Answer (score 1):

You are only seeing Ubuntu because that is the only OS currently on that particular drive `/dev/sda`.

Your image is showing the default drive configuration that you would get when installing Linux, using the option to `Erase disk and install Ubuntu.`  The system would have warned you more than once that it's about to erase everything from the disk, and for you to cancel if you need to back up your files.

If you had chose a different option during the install process, such as `Install Alongside` or `Something else`, then the partition layout would have been different.

The `AlongSide` option have given you the option to split your previous OS (Windows 8) and Ubuntu would have installed in the space that you allocated for it in the split.

The `Something Else` option would have asked you to specify the partition where you want Ubuntu installed.  Ubuntu would have then been installed into that partition and that partition only.

The last two options I explained would have shown your `Windows 8` in the grub menu.  Also the installer would have included all detected Operating Systems in the boot menu as a choice when you boot.

The Ubuntu Install Process is located here:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

**How can I get Windows 8 back?**

Recovering data from a formatted drive isn't an easy task.  Take a look at this link to get started:
[How to recover NTFS drive formatted in ext4?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137698/81664)

The user is recommending tools from lifehacker.com:
http://lifehacker.com/5237503/five-best-free-data-recovery-tools

Comment: Wouldn't the Ubuntu install have overwritten the Windows 8 programs that used to reside in the first parts of the Hard Drive making recovery impossible unlike a simple format command alone.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix The installer deleted all partitions, then created a new partition table with the allocation you see in the Gparted image.  Writing  information to the hard drive comes in layers.  It's much like using a stencil.  If you were able to study the layers fine enough you could pick out certain data that has been overwritten.  Forensic specialist are good at recovering data that was overwritten by reformatting and re-partitioning.  Not an easy task for a layman.  The urgency of the data might determine the (very costly)  time and expense consideration.